# How to generate a params array using coffeescript and data-attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a coffeescript function that returns an array of ID numbers from elements with a 'selected" data attribute.

```
#view (pseudo code!)
<table id='elems_container' data-url=<%= my_path(@object%) >
  <tr data-selected = 'true' data-id = '1'></tr>
  <tr data-selected = 'true' data-id = '2'></tr>
  <tr data-selected = 'false' data-id = '3'></tr>
  <tr data-selected = 'true' data-id = '4'></tr>
</table>

#coffeescript
elems = $("tr[data-selected='true']").map(->
  $(this).data "id"
).get()
$.ajax({ url: $('#elems_container').data('url'), dataType: "script", data: { 'selected_ids': elems } })
```

This returns the following in the logs

```
Started GET "/my/path?selected_ids%5B%5D=1&selected_ids%5B%5D=2&selected_ids%5B%5D=4
```

I now want to select these selected ids in the controller

```
@collection = Model.where('id = ?', params[:selected_ids])
```

Instead this is returning all Models, not just those listed in the params.

Is the get URL correct, or should a params array look different? What else am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you URI-decode your query string, you'll see this:

```
selected_ids[]=1&selected_ids[]=2&selected_ids[]=4
```

When Rails sees the brackets, `[]`, it will create an array in `params[:selected_ids]` holding the values from the query string and you'll have `['1','2','4']` in `params[:selected_ids]`.

When you have multiple values to check, the SQL you want is:

```
where id in (1,2,4)
```

ActiveRecord is smart enough to use the `in` operator when you hand it an array like this:

```
where(:some_column => some_array)
```

so you should be able to say:

```
@collection = Model.where(:id => params[:selected_ids])
```

and get what you're looking for in `@collection`.

Comment: can't believe I overlooked the `in` SQL query! Thanks for the great explanation.